# Spree API - Pull a list of products for guest users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I am building a small subscription-based e-commerce solution with spree. I would like to pull a list of subscription options (monthly, yearly etc.) from spree for users to purchase.

The issue is that the API requires an authentication token to be sent to the endpoint /api/products and therefore isn't suitable for guests hitting the site for the first time.

Is there a way I can pull the list of products from a certain category without needing authentication? I know there is the ability to disable authentication for the API but I don't really want to open up the whole API!

Answer (score 0):

You can allow read-only access to your API by placing this in your config>initializers>spree.rb file:
`Spree::Api::Config[:requires_authentication] = false`

This will NOT open up the whole API. This will only allow read-only access without the need of appending a token. According to the [spree docs](https://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/security.html):

> "For actions that modify data within Spree, a user will (still) need
>   to have an API key and then their user record would need to have
>   permission to perform those actions."

More information here:
https://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/security.html